# Templated Control - content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I'm trying to run the templated user control example provided by MSDN. Code is as follows:

So according to MSDN this should implement as follows:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyAssembly" Namespace="MyAssembly.Controls" TagPrefix="abs" %>
<abs:TemplatedFirstControl id = "First"  runat=server
                           Text= "The time on the server is "  >
      <FirstTemplate>
          <h3><font face="Verdana" color = "red">
                 <%# Container.Text %> <%# Container.DateTime %>
              </font>
          </h3>
      </FirstTemplate>      
    </abs:TemplatedFirstControl>
```

Designer complains that content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags of `TemplatedFirstControl` and that `FirstTemplate` is not supported. So what's missing? I duplicated MSDN's code verbatim

MSDN Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720695%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: what's your definition of the prefix `abs`?

Comment: It's defined in the <%@ Register TagPrefix... declaration in the .aspx.

Comment: consider editing the question to include that Register tag, as well as the link to the MSDN article. Do any web.config entries need to be made as well?

Comment: No. This should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who has the same problem, I found that adding the following attributes to the FirstTemplate property solved the issue for me:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public ITemplate FirstTemplate 
{
    get
    {
        return firstTemplate;
    }
    set
    {
        firstTemplate = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the compiler is not recognizing that FirstTemplate is a valid child element of TemplatedFirstControl. Check the following:

- Is FirstTemplate a public property of the codebehind class of TemplatedFirstControl?
- Is there a public child template control class defined, that derives from Control and implements INamedContainer?
- Is the FirstTemplate property decorated with a TemplateContainer attribute?
- Does that attribute correctly specify the type of the child template control?

Comment: Well as stated I used the exact code in the MSDN article. Which I had recreated here but someone edited my post and commented it all out. TemplatedFirstControl is not usercontrol. It's a server control class. But it looks to me like all those bases are covered.